# Perspective Video inside image

Tags: video, presentation, after-effects

I want to insert a video file (screen recording of an iPhone) inside the **image** of an actual iPhone but in a perspective view.
I found many video-tutorial but all of them are for corner pinning, which doesn't for the images.

So my point is to find a way to make corner pinning for the image and then clip inside this pinned area a video.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead **Corner Pin**, use the **СС Power Pin**, 
which is also a standard plugin. since version cs6, I think.